# simulating app upgrade in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to simulate an upgrade from version 2.0 to 2.1. I have version 2.0 hosted in testflight, so I did install it in my device. Then I tried running the app from xcode. However what happened is that the app did not get overlapped, instead it created two apps with the same name. How can I make it such that when I run the app from xcode it overlays the old version?

I've made sure that the bundle identifier is the same.

Comment: Double check the bundle ID's. These are how iOS determines wether an app is already installed or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well the info you can get while updating can be found @ [this link here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367002/is-device-deployment-enough-to-simulate-application-update)

> when user updates an app, Documents folder is stored as is, including
>   NSUserDefaults (but, sometimes user download app via iTunes and
>   replace the whole application, crying 'OMG! update killed all my
>   levels progress!'); Application bundle is erased and replaced by new
>   one (anyway, it is readonly for user); Re-deployment of new build
>   version will be enough;

You can't access the appstore inside the simulator because: @ [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137791/can-i-access-the-app-store-from-within-the-ios-simulator)

> It's a simulator not an emulator. Even if there was an App Store in
>   the Simulator, none of the apps in the store would work since they are
>   compiled for ARM CPUs while the Simulator runs x86 code.

Another stack overflow @ [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268079/simulating-an-update-in-iphone-sdk) states:

> Build and install your old version, generate some data, and then
>   install the new version on top of it.
>
> For testing before submitting to the Appstore I generally download
>   from the AppStore again the old version, and then install with Xcode
>   the newer version - for your next update... ;-)

And another stack overflow (that I lost the link for) states:

> No, the simulator runs i386 binaries and iPhone appstore apps are ARM
>   binaries apps.
>
> iOS apps are compiled to machine code, Android apps are run in a
>   Virtual Machine using byte code and are translated to machine code at
>   the time they are run.

So no, I don't believe you can run it in the simulator, how ever you can have older projects saved on the iPhone and test both out. And the apple documentation is @ [this link here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.htmldeployment%20of%20new%20build%20version%20will%20be%20enough;)

Comment: also if I upgrade using this method, download the app from test flight and then run the app from xcode.. will I lose all data stored in core data?

Comment: I'm not an expert in core data, but i don't think so, just copy your app, create a new project, call that project yourprojectnamehereTest.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2285/_index.html

You cannot simulate update in XCode (neither in simulator or connected device). You have to create IPA file and simulate update process via iTunes.